# jQuery addClass fadeIn fadeOut

Tags: jquery, fading

```
    $('.a').bind('mouseover',function(){
     $('.a').addClass("b");
     }).bind('mouseout',function(){
     $('.a').removeClass("b");
    });
```

I want to add fadeIn fadeOut in the above code like :

```
$('.a').bind('mouseover',function(){
 $('.a').addClass("b").fadeIn('slow');
 }).bind('mouseout',function(){
 $('.a').removeClass("b").fadeOut('fast');
});
```

But that doesn't work for me...tried to google but that didn't work either.

Comment: are you sure it's $(".a") and not $("a") ?

Comment: Oh yeah! it's `$(".a")`. the above code without fading works fine.

Comment: What doesn't work? No animation? Or does it throw an error?

Comment: No animation and the code which was working above fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is working as in *bug-free* but consider this:

- `fadeOut` hides the element and you won't be able to hover over it again.
- `fadeIn` on an already visible element won't do anything.

Comment: Also consider binding to `mouseenter`/`mouseleave` instead of `mouseover`/`mouseout` to avoid bubbling issues.

Comment: So you mean I can't add animation this way?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I think your `fadeOut` and `fadeIn` are the wrong way around.

You can't fade something *in* on `mouseover`, because the fact you are fading it *in* implies it isn't visible in the first place, hence you can't `mouseover` it.

Assuming this is the case, and you switch them around, this leads to a second problem, once it's faded out `mouseout` will automatically fire because the mouse is no longer over the element because the element isn't visible (you've just faded it *out*).

Can you confirm which effect you are looking for? There may be an alternative.

Comment: Well now I got the point and now I have to use this on 2 different elements. Thanks